# Commerce: Custom template with multiple product references and ajax update

Tags: ajax, commerce

I am about to implement an Drupal commerce system. So far so good, but now I need to have multiple "Product reference"'s from the Product Display to Products.

I allowed my field to have multiple product references and it works: dropdown aside to "add to cart". Since this dropdown uses an ajax call, the rest of my product display does not get updated... But I need to update the SKU and the PRICE for this "new" product too...

Any suggestions?

Code from my node--product.tpl

```
<?php
// @file: node--product.tpl.php
//
// fetch needed vars
if(!empty($content['field_produkt_reference'])){
    $product_number = $content['product:field_manufacturer_number']['#items'][0]['safe_value'];
    $product_sku = $content['product:commerce_price']['#object']->sku;
    $product_warranty = $content['product:field_warranty']['#items'][0]['value'];
    $product_price = $content['product:commerce_price'][0]['#markup'];

    // put them in array > easy render
    $overview[] = array('Herstellernummer' => $product_number);
    $overview[] = array('Artikelnummer' => $product_sku);
    $overview[] = array('Preis' => $product_price);
    $overview[] = array('Add' => render($content['field_produkt_reference']));
}
?>

...

<?php
// iterate through array
// finally lets display fetched data
foreach($overview as $item){
    foreach($item as $description => $value){
        switch($description){
            case 'Preis':
                echo '<tr><td class="price" colspan="2">'. $value .'</td></tr>';
                break;
            case 'Add':
                echo '<tr><td class="add" colspan="2">'. $value .'</td></tr>';
                break;
            default:
                echo '<tr><td>'. $description .'</td><td>'. $value .'</td></tr>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

However when I do not directly call the field values, eg:

```
$product_price = $content['product:commerce_price'][0]['#markup']
```

but call it with the render function:

```
$product_price = render($content['product:commerce_price'])
```

the ajax update works as expected (in this example with the price field of my product) but the result is just a huge messy code... ;-) So I would prefer the direct value call.

--- edit1: better format, adjust title

--- edit2: additional information

Comment: Please make your title reflect your needs a bit more, and remove unneeded spaces in front of your code (you only need 4 for highest-level lines). Can do? :) And could you add `/** @file` comments to your code blocks? I'm not so bad with AJAX, but not so good with drupal commerce, so it would help me to help you if I knew where are you executing these.

Comment: Hi @Mołot ;-) I updated my post and some additional information